# My Google GCP instance disappeared!!! When I add more than 8 in a location some instance randomely disappeared without warning

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying out different features on GCP and something really troubled me. I setup 7 test server and then use the instance group to add a few more. All in a sudden some of the server that has been setup disappeared.

I cannot see any log or activities saying that they were dropped. So I cannot confirm if it is a 8 instance max policy or it is an error or bug on GCP.

Anyone has similar experience? There is no warning or anything stop me adding more test units. It just randomly drop some launched instance....

Comment: Did you set up those VM instances as part of a Managed Instance Group (MIG)? If yes, then the MIG can create and destroy instances. That ability is not a Google bug. Edit your question with details on what you have configured.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'll summarize the two possibilities that you might be facing:

1. The account being used for creating servers is a trial account and the trial period has [expired](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#end). If so, You need to explicitly enable billing during the trial, otherwise your instances will be shutted down when the trial runs out and removed after grace period which are not restorable.

Note: In this possibility all the instances will be deleted at a time when
trail period expires, but as you mentioned only some are randomly getting
disappeared 2nd one can be prompt solution than 1st one.

2.The group where instances are added is Managed Instance Group(MIG)

Here various policies and actions can create, delete, and modify
instances that are managed by a MIG. Those operations are returned as DONE
after the group has scheduled actions to create, delete, or update those
instances. However, this doesn't mean that the instances in the group have
been created, deleted, or updated until those underlying actions are
complete. You can [verify the status of the group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/getting-info-about-migs#verify_group), or alternatively [verify the status of those instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/getting-info-about-migs#verify_instances).